# Percentage of pixels with a specific value

Tags: python, image-processing, statistics, pixel, raster

Is there a transformer that extract me the percentage of pixels with a specific value, and shows it as an attribute? My reader would be a TIFF and the writer would be a CSV file, with the attribute of percentage of black pixels per band.

I have other attributes, result from `RasterStatisticsCalculator`.

[image]

Comment: You want to count pixels with a transformer?

Comment: What is `RasterStatisticsCalculator`? What package does it come from? In what language? Is the Python tag that was added to your question correct?

Comment: @Cris Luengo I think by "transformer" OP does not mean the deep learning model, rather just a function f:I(mxnxk)-> (Nxk) that extracts a set of features from each channel of the image

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can compute the statistics with `numpy` in `python`, the function `prop_black()` can be used to compute the proportion of black pixels in each color channel:

```
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from numpy import mean, min, max, std, sum
import pandas as pd

def prop_black(im):
    return 100*(sum(im == 0) / np.prod(im.shape))

im = imread('lena_color.tiff')
assert(len(im.shape) == 3) # must have color channels

funcs = [mean, min, max, std, sum, prop_black]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['band_index'] + [f.__name__ for f in funcs])

for k in range(im.shape[2]):
    stat_dict = {'band_index': k}
    for func in funcs:
        stat_dict[func.__name__] = func(im[...,k])
    df = df.append(stat_dict, ignore_index=True)
df['band_index'] = df['band_index'].astype(int)

df.head()
# band_index    mean   amin amax    std         sum         prop_black
#0      0   180.223454  0.0 255.0   49.049418   47244497.0  0.000381
#1      1   99.051090   0.0 248.0   52.877750   25965649.0  0.004196
#2      2   105.410038  0.0 225.0   34.058561   27632609.0  0.002670
```

The input image used (`lena_color.tiff`) is attached below:

[image]